# Making a condition out of the addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent') CF7

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form-7

I have here a code that triggers when a particular CF7 form is submitted

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if(event.detail.contactFormId == '11164') {
    jQuery('.pop_timer_box').hide();
    }
}, false );
```

but how can I make this a condition like

```
if (wpcf7mailsent) {
   do this
} elseif (wpcf7mailfail) {
   do this
}
```

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: use two event listener for mail sent and mail fail

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second event listener for failed.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailfailed ', function( event ) {
    alert( "Mail Failed Event" ); // Make this whatever you want.
}, false );
```

[Contact Form 7 Documentation](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/)